# Can we use array.split to split arrays into chunks?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split

I tried

```
    Dim array = New Integer() {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
    Dim splitArray = array.Split(2)
```

[image]

And that's the result. Still one chunk

I look up array.split and it seems that it talks about separators and stuff instead chunk size.

So looks like splitting arrays into chunks are not what it's for.

What is it for?

And can we use it to split array into chunks anyway?

Comment: I think there is a function called chunk. I forget if it's from nuget or from vb.net

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `Array.Split()`. There is a `String.Split()` which is why it talks about "separators and stuff".

You can use `Skip()` and `Take()` pretty easily though:

```
Dim chunkSize As Integer = 2
Dim array = New Integer() {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length \ chunkSize
    Dim chunk = array.Skip(i * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize)
    Debug.Print(String.Join(", ", chunk))
Next
```

Output:

```
10, 20
30, 40
50, 60
```

Comment: I think there is a function called chunk in nuget or something. This one actually have O(n^2) complexity